# Constructing new object types and instances stored elsewhere (not in vals)

Tags: scala, types, scalaz, shapeless

Consider the following classes:

```
case class Address(town:String, street:String, building:Int)
case class Person(name:String, address:Address)
```

The data is stored directly in instances.
I would like to store data in a strictly typed map "elsewhere". Something like:

```
val townSlot = Slot[String]("townSlot")
val streetSlot = Slot[String]("streetSlot")
val buildingSlot = Slot[Int]("buildingSlot")

val nameSlot = Slot[String]("nameSlot")
val addressSlot = Slot[Address]("addressSlot")
```

Then I would like to construct a strictly typed map that resembles `HList`s in **shapeless**. Something like:

```
val mapAddress = townSlot :: streetSlot :: buildingSlot :: EmptyMap
val mapPerson = nameSlot :: addressSlot :: EmptyMap
```

the `mapAddress` should have type that completely describes the set of slots:

```
mapAddress.type =:= Map[townSlot.type :: streetSlot.type :: streetSlot.type]
```

the `mapAddress` instance should contain list of slots (this is easy).

In the end we will get a way to construct composite "objects" that have all benefits of directly declared objects but can be stored "elsewhere". Something like reflection without reflection.

The question is — how to complete the goal? How **scalaz**/ **shapeless** can be used for the purpose?

Comment: Isn't what you are asking for just syntactic sugar for [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)?

Comment: Well, yes. It's a builder. However, it should also construct a type of the result.

Comment: The construction can be used to uniformly process parts of objects (by slot/field). For instance all slots can be made optional, or contain multiple values. And all these in a strictly typed manner.

Comment: Do you really need compile time type safety? Runtime type checking would be easier to do here.

Comment: That's an understatement, runtime checks are trivial so I'm pretty sure he really knows what he needs. As a matter of fact, I have been wanting exactly this feature for some time and have actually been working on it lately (still very much in a wip state though). tHere are definitely use cases where this is immensely useful.

Comment: @Arseniy Zhizhelev: Have you looked into shapeless's extensible  records? Seems close enough to what you want.

Comment: @SpiderPig As for runtime checks it is really easy and I have been using it until now. I had been satisfied with it. However since I saw HLists I'm not comfortable with it anymore. When there is a compile time check that eliminates debugging...

Comment: @Régis Jean-Gilles **Extensible records** seems very close to what I want. Case class as HLists representation is also very interesting. Thank you for pointing me on them.

I'll try to construct the typed map with the shapeless approach.

Comment: I've tried **Extensible records**. I think they have a couple of shortcomings when used for updating: (1) the updated object has weird type with `Updater`; (2) new fields can be added unconstrained; (3) the type of object grows on every update; (4) no obvious way to deal with inner records updates.